# Typescript & Knockout.js Math.max computed

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I'm trying to create a dynamic steps system for a website I'm working on.

It should display current step out of total steps and change current and/or total steps depending on conditions.

e.g.

Step 1/2

Step 2/2

Unfortunately I'm running into a problem I'm not sure how to diagnose because I don't know why it's giving me the error.

The error is:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'StepNumberOne' of undefined"

Here's my code:

```js
class ViewModel {
  public IsStepOneActive: KnockoutObservable < boolean > ;
  public IsStepTwoActive: KnockoutObservable < boolean > ;

  public StepNumberOne: KnockoutComputed < number > ;
  public StepNumberTwo: KnockoutComputed < number > ;

  public Total: KnockoutComputed < number > ;

  constructor() {
    this.IsStepOneActive = ko.observable(true);
    this.IsStepTwoActive = ko.observable(false);

    this.StepNumberOne = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      if (this.IsStepOneActive()) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });

    this.StepNumberTwo = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      if (this.IsStepTwoActive()) {
        return 2;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });

    this.Total = ko.computed(function() {
      return Math.max(this.StepNumberOne(), this.StepNumberTwo);
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: StepNumberOne"></span>
    <span> / </span>
    <span data-bind="text: Total"></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: StepNumberTwo"></span>
    <span> / </span>
    <span data-bind="text: Total"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `data-bind` attribute insetead of `data-binding`

Additionally you need to change:

```
ko.computed(() => {
  return Math.max(this.StepNumberOne(), this.StepNumberTwo);
});
```

You need to have the delegate there because the scope will be different there

Comment: Sorry, this is an example I made, I meant data-bind